# Experimenting with ruby inheritance

Tags: ruby

How would you get my 'def showVars' built within the 'second' class to output the 'puts (variables)' that it inherited from the 'First' class?

```
class First
  @@varOne = 1 
  CONSTANT_ONE = 10 
end

class Second < First
  def showVars
    puts @@varOne
    puts CONSTANT_ONE
  end
end
```

My failed attempt:

```
class First
  @@varOne = 1 
  CONSTANT_ONE = 10 
end

class Second < First
  def showVars
    puts @@varOne
    puts CONSTANT_ONE
  end
end

puts Second.showVars # <-- fails
```

Comment: Define "fails".

Comment: `puts Second.new.showVars` Works. You have defined an **instance** method, not a **class** method.

Comment: I see Thank you.

Comment: Ruby *strongly* recommends naming methods and variables with only lowercase letters, that is this should be `show_vars`. Capital letters are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` situations and have specific meaning in the syntax.

Comment: Good to know thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `Second.showVars` because it's an instance method. To call it that way, you have to use a class method. You can do that by adding `self` in the method name.

```
class First
  @@varOne = 1 
  CONSTANT_ONE = 10 
end

class Second < First
  def self.showVars
    puts @@varOne
    puts CONSTANT_ONE
  end
end

puts Second.showVars
```

The output now is:

```
1
10

[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Class methods are equivalent to static methods in other languages.

Another point I noticed is that you named your method `showVars` using `camelCase`. Ruby methods should be named using [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).